# How can lambda expressions as event handlers can change local variables?

Tags: c#, lambda, event-handling

I was writing some tests for one of my classes and I needed to test that an event was being raised.  Out of just trying it and seeing what happened I coded something similar to the following extremely simplified code.

```
public class MyEventClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
    public void MethodThatRaisesMyEvent()
    {
        if (MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class MyEventClassTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void EventRaised()
    {
        bool raised = false;
        var subject = new MyEventClass();
        subject.MyEvent += (s, e) => raised = true;

        subject.MethodThatRaisesMyEvent();

        Assert.IsTrue(raised);
    }
}
```

I wasn't so much amazed when it worked as when I started to try and figure out how it worked.  Specifically, how would I write this without lambda expressions so that the local variable `raised` can be updated?  In other words, how is the compiler refactoring/translating this?

I got this far...

```
[TestClass]
public class MyEventClassTestRefactor
{
    private bool raised;

    [TestMethod]
    public void EventRaised()
    {
        raised = false;
        var subject = new MyEventClass();
        subject.MyEvent += MyEventHandler;

        subject.MethodThatRaisesMyEvent();

        Assert.IsTrue(raised);
    }

    private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        raised = true
    }
}
```

But this changes `raised` to a class-scoped field rather than a local-scope variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Specifically, how would I write this without lambda expressions so that the local variable raised can be updated?

You would create an extra class, to hold the *captured variables*. That's what the C# compiler does. The extra class would contain a method with the body of the lambda expression, and the `EventRaised` method would create an *instance* of that capturing class, using the variables within that instance instead of "real" local variables.

It's easiest to demonstrate this without using events - just a small console application. Here's the version with the lambda expression:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int x = 10;
        Action increment = () => x++;

        increment();
        increment();
        Console.WriteLine(x); // 12
    }
}
```

And here's code which is similar to the code generated by the compiler:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    private class CapturingClass
    {
        public int x;

        public void Execute()
        {
            x++;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        CapturingClass capture = new CapturingClass();
        capture.x = 10;
        Action increment = capture.Execute;

        increment();
        increment();
        Console.WriteLine(capture.x); // 12
    }
}
```

Of course it can get *much* more complicated than this, particularly if you have multiple captured variables with different scopes - but if you can understand how the above works, that's a big first step.

Comment: Jon Skeet to the rescue, again!

Comment: Yea! I was hoping either you or Mr. Lippert would reply!  Accepted (as soon as I can).

Answer (score 1):

Compiler generates class like this, which has method with signature of lambda delegate. All captured local variables moved to this class fields:

```
public sealed class c_0
{
    public bool raised;

    public void m_1(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
       // lambda body goes here
       raised = true;
    }
}
```

And final compiler trick is replacing usages of local `raised` variable with this field of generated class:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyEventClassTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void EventRaised()
    {
        c_0 generated = new c_0();
        generated.raised = false;

        var subject = new MyEventClass();
        subject.MyEvent += generated.m_1;

        subject.MethodThatRaisesMyEvent();

        Assert.IsTrue(generated.raised);
    }
}
```

Comment: Complete with Russian accent!  Awesome!