# Using an object passed as a parameter to a function in an inner anonymous function C#

Tags: c#, events, anonymous-function

Just for testing purposes, I've created a class **MyData** that holds an int property called Id.

```
public class MyData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in an Main function of an App Console, I initialize two instances of this class.

```
MyData myData = new MyData() { Id = 1 },
            myData2 = new MyData() { Id = 2 };
```

And a new object called **Property**. It's simple an object holding a value and trigger an event when that value changes.

```
Property p = new Property("Test",
            "System.String",
            "c");
```

So I simply create a new Property called `Test` holding an object of type `System.String` initialized to "c".

Now, I want to set a binding, for example I want to increment the Id of myDatas when the value of the Property changes.

So I've created this static function:

```
private static void SetBinding(Property p,
    MyData test)
{
    p.PropertyChanged += ((o, r) => 
    {
        test.Id++;
    });
}
```

And call it into the Main method:

```
SetBinding(p, myData);
SetBinding(p, myData2);
```

Debugging, I saw that the Ids are actually incremented. So it seems to work but... I'm not sure about that. In which way the anonymous function keeps track of the variable to modify? Maybe there is a scenario where this my implementation doesn't work anymore?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082471/where-is-the-captured-variables-allocated-in-nested-function-in-c-sharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635420/how-can-lambda-expressions-as-event-handlers-can-change-local-variables/13635462#13635462) might answer your question but I wouldn't call it an exact duplicate of either of those.

Comment: If you really want to understand what's going on, you should open this assembly in ILSpy (or a similar tool) and look at how the code is translated. You'll see the details that are explained in the links above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler generates an additional class...

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1_0
{
    public MyData test;

    internal void <SetBinding>b__0(object o, PropertyChangedEventArgs r)
    {
        test.Id++;
    }
}
```

...and replaces your anonymous function with a similar function of the generated class:

```
private static void SetBinding(Property p, MyData test)
{
    var a = new <>c__DisplayClass1_0();
    a.test = test;
    p.PropertyChanged += a.<SetBinding>b__0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Jann Westermann ... Another question, please... When does the CompilerGenerated class become available for GarbageCollector? I suppose when I deatch all the delegates from the PropertyChanged event. Am I wrong?